# change UIButton click area after adding image programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sdwebimage

I'm using a UIButton as a link, theres a change there will be no image so I have it set to 0 height but its a loose priority so when I add an image it will expand. Issue is the clickable area isn't expanding with the image being added.

Currently Im trying to add the image like this.

```
    [self.advertisementButton sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] 
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.advertisementButton setFrame:self.advertisementButton.imageView.bounds];
    [self.advertisementButton layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Are you setting `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on your `UIImageView`?

Comment: its a UIButton and it works just only when I click the very top of the image.

Comment: What does `sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL` do?

Comment: downloads an image (using SDwebimage) and sets it as the background image of the button. Im thinking the issue is that its not making the actual frame bigger. hence the second line where im trying to make it bigger (but it probably doesnt work)

Answer (score 0):

First you download your image, then set you button frame with the image size.
Here you are taking the button's `imageView` property to set the `button frame`

```
// Download like
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"imageurl"]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

// Set frame like
    [advertisementButton setFrame:CGRectMake(advertisementButton.frame.origin.x, advertisementButton.frame.origin.y, image.size.width , image.size.height)];
```

Comment: doesnt work for me... same issue of just the original bounds being clickable